# Why do some transformers hum less or not at all when lightly loaded?

Tags: transformer, back-emf

It can be observed that large power transformers hum more under load. For example, when some devices are powered up, there is brief "twang" sound: a loud hum that quickly decays as the filter capacitors charge. Increased continuous hum from a transformer can indicate that the filter capacitors are leaking.

This question isn't about why transformers hum, but why do they hum less, or hardly at all, when not loaded. How is the electro-mechanics playing itself out to reduce the hum? After all, the fluctuating magnetic fields are there whether or not there is a load on the secondary winding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The humming is primarily caused by magnetic forces, which are proportional to current.  Less loaded transformers have less current thru them, so hum less.

Comment: That simple. Okay.

Comment: @Olin - Magnetisation current may complicate that somewhat.